# two qt ui header file namespace issue

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two ui header - *ui_FlowChartEditor.h* and *ui_Notepad.h*

There was a problem with this codes :

```
//ui_FlowChartEditor.h
namespace Ui {
    class FlowChartEditorClass: public Ui_FlowChartEditorClass {};
} // namespace Ui
```

```
//ui_Notepad.h
namespace Ui {
    class NotepadClass: public Ui_NotepadClass {};
} // namespace Ui
```

'Ui' namespace was duplicated, so I solve this problem by changing name of namespace.

like this :

```
//ui_FlowChartEditor.h
namespace Ui_FlowChartEditor {
    class FlowChartEditorClass: public Ui_FlowChartEditorClass {};
} // namespace Ui
```

```
//ui_Notepad.h
namespace Ui_Notepad {
    class NotepadClass: public Ui_NotepadClass {};
} // namespace Ui
```

It works at Debug configuration, but not at Release configuration.

Compiler says : [error C2653: 'Ui_FlowChartEditor': is not a class or namespace name (compiling source file FlowChartEditor.cpp)], etc..

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**With @zgyarmati's solution, I solved this problem.**

I changed objectName in Qt Designer.
[image]

ui_ header file became like this:

```
namespace FlowChartEditorUi {
    namespace Ui {
        class FlowChartEditorClass : public Ui_FlowChartEditorClass {};
    } // namespace Ui
} // namespace FlowChartEditorUi
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui_*.h` files are regenerated by `uic` from your forms (.ui) files. You changed the generated `ui_*.h` files only for the debug build, but not for the release build, so you have the pristine, uic-generated files there. 
You could change the files also for the release build, but
you are not supposed to change the generated files, as they will be overwritten.
To set a namespace for your ui class, when you are creating a Designer Form Class in QtCreator, specify a name with a namespace, e.g. Ui_Notepad::NotepadClass in the "Class name" field, and the generated `ui_*.h` file will contain that namespace.

If you already have your forms, then you can also change the "objectName" property for them accordingly in the QtCreator form editor.